# Zend framework - connection to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework, connection

I encountered troubles when trying to connect to postgresql database within Zend framework application. In my application.ini I use

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_PGSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = testtest
resources.db.params.dbname = testdb
```

But when I run the application, I got an error message 
Message: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not create socket: Address family not supported by protocol.

Could you please tell me what can be wrong?

Zend version 1.12.3., PostgreSQL version 9.0.7, PHP version 5.3.5.

Thanks, Marek .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` on your machine is (most likely) resolving to the IPv6 address of localhost (`::1`), but since the protocol/module used does not support IPv6 connections, your connection fails.

You could either;

- Use `127.0.0.1` as a host instead, that will force a connection to the IPv4 localhost.
- Remove the host line completely, that will force a connection via UNIX sockets.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but after changing the host to 127.0.0.1, I got the message: Message: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? I usually connect to the database via the psql client or pgAdmin, this works. Any outher ideas why it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @MarekHajžman Then it seems your PostgreSQL is not listening to the network (at least localhost) at all. Try removing the `host` line completely, it should (unless it works unlike other PDO implementations) default to UNIX sockets instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server:
>   Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost"
>   (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? in
>   lock_may_be_available() (line of /app/ctr/ctr
>   web/drupal/includes/lock.inc).

The problem was caused because of a full disk. and PostgreSQL DB blocked/froze.
Making some free space and restarting of PostgreSQL DB resolved my problem.